# NMaximize not finding global maximum

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I'm trying to find the place on a highway that's furthest from it's nearest gas station. Here are the functions I'm using.

```
dist[x_?NumericQ, stations_] := Abs[x - Nearest[stations, x][[1]]];
maxdist[lowerbound_, upperbound_, stations_] :=
NMaximize[{dist[x, stations], lowerbound < x < upperbound}, x];
```

Here are the mile markers of my gas stations:

```
stations={22, 25, 27, 31, 34, 42, 47, 52, 54, 62, 63, 70, 71, 74, 78, 80, 
   84, 101, 106, 110, 115, 136, 137, 143, 149, 151, 154, 169, 174, 175, 176,
   182, 184, 196, 206, 215, 220, 221, 226, 231, 245, 254, 257, 264, 270, 
   272};
```

`maxdist[20,272,stations]` yields `{8.5,{x->92.5}}`

But that's obviously not the largest, as `dist[125.5,stations]` gives `10.5`. Why is `NMaximize` not finding that global maximum?

**A side note:** There is an obvious workaround that avoids `NMaximize` (see below), but I'm curious to know why `NMaximize` isn't working.

```
maxdist2[lowerbound_, upperbound_, stations_] := Max[Table[dist[x, 
    stations], {x, lowerbound, upperbound, 0.5}]]
```

Comment: simply your function is nonlinear and `NMaximise` is not guaranteed to find a global maximum.  `Plot[dist[x, stations], {x, 20, 272}]`

Comment: @george2079 Hmm... I suppose that is probably it. But why does the documentation suggest that it tries to find the global maximum? From the documentation: "NMaximize always attempts to find a global maximum of f subject to the constraints given." I guess it tried but failed. Maybe `Nearest[]` is making it hard for it.

Comment: its the `if linear` .. `otherwise` bullet items under details that bite you here.

Comment: Indeed. So I guess the documentation doesn't promise anything. I just expected a slightly better effort from `NMaximize` than the one I got! Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: total aside but if you are on the highway the distance to a gas station that is behind you doesn't do you much good (Wish whoever coded my garmin understood that! )

Comment: That's true. But then the distance that interests you is just double the distance that I calculate above. So I have that either way and it's just a question of which I choose to report. I agree that the doubled number is the more relevant one for most considerations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you really have this simple 1-d problem you know the answer is the midpoint between the furthest spaced stations. get the answer quickly like this:

```
(Mean /@ #)[[Ordering[Abs[Subtract @@@ #]][[-1]]]] &@
  Partition[Sort@stations, 2, 1] // N
```

> 125.5

Comment: This is very nice, but your comment is actually a better answer than this as my question is on the cause of the failure (and I have my own workaround in the question). Maybe edit this to incorporate your comments and I'll select this as the answer?

Answer (score 1):

We can find the maximum difference between two stations simply with

```
max = MaximalBy[Partition[stations, 2, 1], Differences]
```

> {{115, 136}}

```
Mean @@ max // N
```

> 125.5